# SQL Work Week in format yyyyww

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime

Does anyone know how i can filter a table by next weeks work week in the format `201337` which is `yyyyww` format.

The table would look like this

```
  ww    col1
201336   xx
201337   yy
201338   zz
```

i want to select `201336 xx`.  I normally use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for `timeDate:now` but not sure how to get that to `yyyyww`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @nextWeek datetime
SET @nextWeek = DATEADD(day,7,GETDATE())

SELECT * FROM YourTable
WHERE ww = 
  CAST(DATEPART(year , @nextWeek) as char(4)) + 
  CAST(DATEPART(week , @nextWeek) as char(2))
```

See it working [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/39e61/1).

Comment: The datepart(week,date) unfortunately doesn't return the iso standard week. 'Isoweek' is available as an option in newer versions of SQL server, but the attribute 'year' does not necessarily correspond with the correct iso standard week which could lead to unfortunate results.